# FluentAssertions AllProperties().NotEqualTo()?

Tags: fluent-assertions

Guess I miss something obvious, or could it be that I use and old version (1.7.1.1)?

I write a test for my updateMyDto method.

I want my assert to look like =>

```
updatedDto.ShouldHave().AllProperties().NotEqualTo(originalDto);
```

So I could verify that my updated values was updated.

Any trick to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that syntax doesn't exist. In fact, even the newer versions of Fluent Assertions don't offer this kind of assertion. The property equivalency functionality is meant for comparing two objects are structural equivalent. Not the other way around.